# Necessary condition for grammar ambiguity

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, ambiguity, formal-languages

In my notebook I wrote:

The necessary condition for grammar ambiguity is

1. It contains the rule `A->BB`, where A and B are non-terminals.
2. OR it contains the rule `A->a|b`, where A is a non-terminal and {a,b} are terminals.

Would you please confirm or refute this statement?

Comment: The definition of ambiguous grammar is clear: there is more than one derivation for a sentence in the language. I don't remember an algorithmic solution for finding if a grammar is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not true because there are other ambiguous grammars that don't have either of those rules.

For example `cc` can be produced by `A -> Bc -> cc` but also by `A -> cC -> cc` in the following grammar:

```
A -> Bc | cC
B -> c
C -> c
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible that the teacher was talking about a grammar that is the product of some kind of simplifying algorithm? Your example could be simplified to A -> cc | cc.

Comment: It could be that the teacher was giving examples of ambiguous grammars with those rules. Although I don't see why having the second type of rule would lead to an ambiguous grammar.

Comment: @Grant Actually `A -> cc | cc` is the same as writing `A -> cc` which is *not* ambiguous. Remember that a formal grammar is a **set** of productions of the form `α -> β`. And `{α -> β, α -> β} = {α -> β}` since sets don't contain duplicates. However you can simplify the grammar in the answer to: `A -> Ac | cA | c`.